# How to run thread if multiple data is insert in the multiple table

Tags: c, server, sqlite

I'm facing problem in gsoap , if two user go to register
    at a same time then database is
    locked, i think its threading problem , 
    how to handle it, please insist me. I am running multiple threads in background. every 5 seconds sending data to server.

Comment: write a thread safe code and check your Sqlite features - http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, when working with a database it should be set up so you don't have to worry about things like that.  As EIYusubov suggested, you need to look into the code you are using for for DB access.  What types of reads and writes are you requesting?

(Most) DBs are intended to be multi-user and multi-threaded / multi-session.  Sending data every five seconds (as suggested by Tech.Rahul) is or should be nothing to a DB server, and you shouldn't have any lock contention.

It's possible you could have a case where one user is getting stale data.

```
User A @ 4.9 seconds - retrieves dataset XYZ^1 
User B @ 5.0 seconds - updates dataset XYZ^1 to become => XYZ^2
User C @ 5.1 seconds - retrieves dataset XYZ^2
```

*Note: times in the example are just arbitrary*

So User C wouldn't have what User A is looking at, but that' not going to cause a deadlock situation as you described.  Given the short amount of time elapsed between User A and User C, then User A could be said to be looking at dirty data.